# ¿Cómo retornar múltiples valores (String, Datatable) en un mismo método?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, lista

¿Cómo puedo hacer el retorno de dos valores que sean de diferente tipo de dato, pero que ambos se necesiten enviar al mismo tiempo y dentro del mismo método?.

Este es el código actual:

```
#region getPlanta
[WebMethod]
public static List<DataTable> getPlanta()
{
    List<DataTable> listado = new List<DataTable>();
    string resultado = "";
    Empresa empresa = new Empresa();
    resultado = empresa.getPlanta();
    string conteo=resultado.Substring(resultado.Length - 1);
listado=getAutorizaciones(conteo);

    return resultado+"|"+listado; -- ERROR
}
#endregion
```

En lo que a mi respecta, la forma en que lo retorno actualmente es de tipo cadena y necesito retornar un valor en forma de listado, pero no he podido hacer el envío en forma de listado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día, para realizar lo que deseas hacer hay 3 opciones.

1. Crear un objeto que contenga como atributos los dos tipos que quieras regresar
2. Crear un `struct` que esté conformado por los dos tipos que quieras retornar
3. Pasar un valor por referencia y reportar otro.

Aquí te agrego como hacer cada uno de estos.

**Objeto**

```
public class myClaseConjunta
    {
        private String myVar;

        public String MyProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }
        private List<DataTable> myTable;

        public List<DataTable> MyTable
        {
            get { return myTable; }
            set { myTable = value; }
        }    
    }
//Despues tienes tu método

public static myClaseConjunta getPlanta()
{
//haces lo que ocupas y retornas el objeto myClassConjunta
}
```

**Struct**

//Declaras el struct dentro de un `namespace`

```
public struct myStruct 
{
   String myVar;
   List<DataTable> myTable;

   public void SetValues(string _myVar, List<DataTable> _myTable)
   {myVar = _myVar; myTable = _myTable;}

   public String getmyVar()
   {return myVar;}

   public List<DataTable> myTable getmyTable()
   {return myTable;}
}
//Despues tienes tu método

public static myStruct  getPlanta()
{
//haces lo que ocupas y retornas el objeto myClassConjunta
//este no me agrada porque no deberías de usar structs en C#, sino objetos
}
```

**Valor por Referencia**

```
//Tienes tu método que retorna algo y el otro valor lo pasas por referencia y lo modificas en el método y ya irá con el valor cambiado.
public static List<DataTable> getPlanta(ref String myVar)
{
   String = "Nuevo texto";
   return new List<DataTable>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tuve el mismo Problema necesitaba devolver 3 resultados distintos.

Debes definir el valor devuelto por el metodo de Tipo **Tuple** para retornar varios valores:
**Tuple.Create(Valor1,Valor2,Valor3)**

```
public Tuple<bool,double,double> RetornoSegunOrigen (long Id)
{
  double AreaMax = 0, AreaMin = 0;
  bool AreaPagada=false;
  return Tuple.Create(AreaPagada, AreaMin,AreaMax);
}
```

Como puedes observar en el return utiliza **Tuple.Create** al momento de obtenerlo lo capturas con la variable de tipo **var** de Visual Studio C#. 
Revisa el ejemplo

Lo recibes de la siguiente manera:

```
    var resultado = new RetornoSegunOrigen(valor);
    bool areaPagada=resultado.Item1;
    double areaMin=resultado.Item2;
    double areaMax=resultado.Item3;
```

De esa manera tienes diferentes valores.
Mas informacion en [Clase Tuple microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: que bueno que colocaste como recuperar el valor, me ha sido de mucha ayuda tu respuesta

Comment: Carlo Arauz Mucha gracias me sirvió mucho la opcion 2

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con `Tuple`

```
public Tuple<string, List<DataTable>> getPlanta()
{
    List<DataTable> data;
    string str = "El texto que necesitas";
    return Tuple.Create(str, data);
}
```